# slowness when debugging the Grails

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, grails

I'm facing a massive slowness in Grails application debugging startup in eclipse and also navigating through the application after starting the debugging. It takes about 9 minutes to start up in debug mode and around 2 or 2.5 minutes to move from page to page , although it is working fine in the run mode.
I'm using :

```
Grails 2.5.1 , eclipse Luna , JDK 1.7_80, Windows 7 64bit , RAM: 8 GB
```

I disabled the Antivirus. I run `clean` command , nothing changed.

It's very annoying issue. Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: How are you doing it? What's the command you used for debugging?Try it with grails --debug-fork.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any method breakpoints enabled (debugging a whole method as oppose to debugging a line of code in a method).

Comment: @defectus you are right , there were some breakpoints on the whole methods , when i removed them the debug worked fine , but why is this ? can't i put breakpoints on the whole methods without affecting the performance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because debugging on a method level turns the JVM into a fully interpreted mode. So there's no JIT compilation, no optimization etc.

So my advice is to use method level breakpoints only as the last resort when everything fails (and never use it anywhere near the production environment!).